# Блок try-catch. Не весь код работает внутри блока

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

в Блоке try не вызывается функция e.target.reset() и toast.success('Success'). Но данные отправляются удачно. Помогите пожалуйста

```
try {
      toast.success('Success')
      e.target.reset()
      const {data} = await axios.post('/api/email', {
        email,
        subject,
        message,
        phone,
        title,
        mailing
      })
    } catch (err) {
      toast.error(err.response && err.response.data.message
          ? (err.response.data.message)
          : err.message)
        e.target.reset()
    }
```

Comment: Если они не вызываются, но ошибка не происходит, значит вызываются. Что такое toast и e.target?

Comment: e.target это форма (<Form/>)
toast - это библиотека для React чтоб выводить уведомления

Comment: Если axios запрос отправляется, значит ошибок нет.